# Collatz conjecture but with $n^2-1$ instead of $3n+1.$ Does the sequence starting with $13$ go to infinity?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Let's consider the following variant of Collatz $(3n+1) : $

If $n$ is odd then $n \to n^2-1.$

$1\to 0.$

$3\to 8\to 1\to 0.$

$5\to 24\to 3\to 0.$

$7\to 48\to 3\to 0.$

$9\to 80\to 5\to 0.$

$11\to 120\to 15\to 224\to 7\to 0.$

$\color{red}{13\to 168\to 21\to 440\to 55\to 3024\to 189\to 35720\to 4465\to 19936224\to 623007\to\ldots\ ?}\ $

> Does the sequence starting with $13$ go off to infinity? If yes, what
> is a proof? If no, is there a  starting number whose sequence does go off to infinity, and
> how do we prove either that such a number must exist, or even better that a specific starting number goes off to infinity?

Here is some Python code I ran, which suggests that the numbers in the sequence starting at $13$ quickly become large:

```
n=13
num_loops=0
print(n)
while n!=0:
    if n%2==0:
        n//=2
    else: n=n**2-1
    print('\n', n)
    num_loops+=1
    if num_loops==70:
        print("too many loops")
        break
```

Comment: You may get better performance out of your code if you use if n%2==0 (rather than if math.floor((n/2))==n/2); and n //=2 (rather than n/=2)...then you will never get into floats at all.

Comment: You get provably unbounded orbits if you replace $n^2 - 1 $   by $n^2 + 1  $

Comment: @WillJagy feel free to elaborate…

Comment: Keep in mind that it may not run off to infinity. For example, in the $3n-1$ variation, 7 gets stuck in a loop 7, 20, 10, 5, 14, 7,...

Comment: $n^2+1$ never divides by $4$ so at each step you divide by two and then square and that obviously goes to infinity with any odd from $3$ on;  $n^2-1$ always divides by $4$ and of course many times by more so you have big reductions and big increases so numerics may not be that conclusive

Comment: All odd numbers except $2^k \pm 1$ will lead to greater next odd number, and also $2^k \pm 1$ will spiral down to $0$ afterwards, so a sequence will increase forever iff it avoids integers of this form

Comment: After 100 iterations, we get a number that is 936145 bits long. That looks a lot like infinity to me, but appearances can be deceptive.

Comment: Adam, $n^2 + 1  $ cannot be divisible by $4$. The division by $2$  happens exactly once each time.   so the sequence,   beginning with any odd $a_0$ and ignoring the even elements,  is simply $ a_{k+1}  = \frac {1 + a_k^2}{2 }$

Comment: From a heuristic viewpoint, it seems highly likely that some of these sequences will head off to infinity. Consider $x = 4465$, near the end of the portion of the sequence you gave for $13$. You multiply it by $4465$. If we want that number to come down lower than where we started, we need it to be divisible by at least $2^13 = 8192$. That might happen sometimes, but it has to happen multiple times. For $3 < x < 10003$, the average exponent of two that divides $x^2-1$ is $4$.

Comment: More specifically, all of the values for which $(x^2-1)/2^k < x$ are those where $x = 2^m \pm 1$, i.e., $3,5,7,9,15,17,31,33, \cdots$. So a sequence has to get to one of those (as $11$ does), or it'll head off to infinity.

Comment: I think I understand Conrad, Sil's and Will Jagy's comments now. I'll look at Eric's later. Also I'm not sure why Lulu deleted her answer...

Comment: @EricSnyder   I think you have found the key to it. Very nice.

Comment: @WillJagy Well, I didn't actually prove anything, that was empirical only.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy This question is part of the [recreational-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-mathematics) tag, so it is for fun

Comment: @EricSnyder  I posted a proof of your comment

Comment: @EricSnyder - I constructed a tabular view of the transfers from $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ (or "$n \to f(n)$") where in the 4'th and 5'th row the decreases can nicely be seen when reading from right. The ngative values are of no impact, but to assign negative values at the $x$ in the rhs allows to formulate the whole table in simple polynomials with its argument from $\mathbb Z$ and a parameter $e$ for assigning a power of $2$ as factor.

Comment: Adam - you might like a "curious fact" about the iteration starting at $n=a_1=13$ (however could only look towards *30* iterations). See appendix at my updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

The set of solutions can be written as table, segmented by e'th powers of $2$ :

```
  t |     e=0                  |       e=1                  |       e=2                  |    e=3                      |    e=4                       |   ...
----+--------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+---- 
    |         ...              |           ...              |           ...              |           ...               |            ...               |
  -4|  56*2^2  =  (-15)^2-1    |   105*2^3  =  (-29)^2-1    |   203*2^4  =  (-57)^2-1    |   399*2^5  =  (-113)^2-1    |    791*2^6  =  (-225)^2-1    | 
  -3|  30*2^2  =  (-11)^2-1    |    55*2^3  =  (-21)^2-1    |   105*2^4  =  (-41)^2-1    |   205*2^5  =   (-81)^2-1    |    405*2^6  =  (-161)^2-1    | 
  -2|  12*2^2  =   (-7)^2-1    |    21*2^3  =  (-13)^2-1    |    39*2^4  =  (-25)^2-1    |    75*2^5  =   (-49)^2-1    |    147*2^6  =   (-97)^2-1    | 
    |
  -1|   2*2^2  =   (-3)^2-1    |     3*2^3  =   (-5)^2-1    |     5*2^4  =   (-9)^2-1    |     9*2^5  =   (-17)^2-1    |     17*2^6  =   (-33)^2-1    | 
   0|   0*2^2  =    (1)^2-1    |     1*2^3  =    (3)^2-1    |     3*2^4  =    (7)^2-1    |     7*2^5  =    (15)^2-1    |     15*2^6  =    (31)^2-1    | 
    |
   1|   6*2^2  =    (5)^2-1    |    15*2^3  =   (11)^2-1    |    33*2^4  =   (23)^2-1    |    69*2^5  =    (47)^2-1    |    141*2^6  =    (95)^2-1    | 
   2|  20*2^2  =    (9)^2-1    |    45*2^3  =   (19)^2-1    |    95*2^4  =   (39)^2-1    |   195*2^5  =    (79)^2-1    |    395*2^6  =   (159)^2-1    | 
   3|  42*2^2  =   (13)^2-1    |    91*2^3  =   (27)^2-1    |   189*2^4  =   (55)^2-1    |   385*2^5  =   (111)^2-1    |    777*2^6  =   (223)^2-1    | 
   4|  72*2^2  =   (17)^2-1    |   153*2^3  =   (35)^2-1    |   315*2^4  =   (71)^2-1    |   639*2^5  =   (143)^2-1    |   1287*2^6  =   (287)^2-1    | 
    |         ...              |           ...              |           ...              |           ...               |            ...               |
----+--------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+----
```

meaning always $$n_2 \cdot 4\cdot  2^e = n_1 ^2 -1 \tag 1 $$

Here $n_2=f_e(t)$ can be written as a quadratic and $n_1=g_e(t)$ as a linear polynomial in $t \in \mathbb Z$. The shown data would have rowindices $t$ in the interval $t=-4..+4$.

We can construct the polynomials in $t$ from the values in a column with the rowindex taken as $t$ in the interval $-4...4$ and can then write
$$ \begin{array} {} 
f_e(t) &= 4 \cdot 2^e \cdot t \cdot (t+1)-2 \cdot t+2^e-1 \\
g_e(t) &= 4 \cdot 2^e \cdot t+2 \cdot 2^e-1
\end{array} \tag 2$$

A better memorizable version is this:
$$ \begin{array} {} 
f_e(t) = 2^e \cdot (2 t +1)^2-(2 t+1) \\
g_e(t) = 2^e \cdot 2 \cdot (2  \cdot t+1 )-1
\end{array} \tag 3$$
and replacing the odd values $2t+1$ by $u \in \mathbb Z $ \ $ 2 \mathbb Z $ gives the even shorter:
$$ \begin{array} {} 
f_e(u) = u \cdot (2^e \cdot u-1) \\
g_e(u) = 2 \cdot (2^e \cdot u-1)+1
\end{array} \tag 4$$

To prove equality according to (1) it suffices to expand and insert this into the equation (1):
$$ 4 \cdot 2^e \cdot f_e(u) = g_e(u)^2 - 1 \tag 5$$
We find the equality in a few steps.

---

*Relation to Sil's and EricSnyder's comments and @WillJagy's analysis:
in the table the $4$'th and $5$'th rows contain the cases,
where $n_2 \lt \mid n_1 \mid $, which has been problematized
by Will Jagy's answer; his notation $(2^k,x,y)$ there is
my notation  $(4 \cdot 2^e,n_1,n_2)$ here.*

***Update***:  This idea seems to allow to proceed to a proof, that there are
only finitely many other orbits towards zero than that of $n_1=2^k \pm 1$
with $k>2$  (or $4 \cdot 2^e$ with $e>0$), and that there are no cycles
and that thus all other orbits diverge infinitely.

The critical two types of $n_1$ occur regularly in row $t=-1$ and $t=0$,
so we need only find $n_1$ where the related $n_2$ has the form $2^k \pm 1$ in the
other rows $t<-1 $ or $t>0$, which would iterate then to the center rows and
thus to zero.

(a): Searching the rectangle $(t,e)=(-800...800,1..31)$ we find only three solutions:
$$ (t,e,n_1,n_2) \in  \{ (1,2,23,33), (-23,1,-181,4095), (1,1,11,15) \} \tag 6$$
so $n_1=11$, $n_1=23$ and $n_1=181$ iterate towards zero.

(b): Now it could happen, that the $n_1$ values $(23),(181),(11)$ occur as $n_2$ values
elsewhere, with three other values $n_1$ and are thus themselves iterates.
But this does not happen, and fortunately we need only a finite searchspace
to prove this: using the ordering of the $n_2$ values in a column and along the
rows.

So if we could prove, that indeed the three cases (a) are the only ones, we had
solved the problem in the OP. It seems to me, that an "A. Baker"-style proof
might be possible to limit the search-space to a finite rectangle,
but I've not so much expertise to do that on my own, at least at the moment.
But there are results about the distance of squares and powers of $2$ available,
so maybe we need only refer to one of that results.
See for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396729/how-close-is-an-odd-power-of-two-to-a-perfect-square) recent question in MSE and especially Mike Bennet's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4396749).

***Update2: Proof for (eq.6)***
The case is indeed solvable; there is an article of Laszlo Szalai, 2001 who deals with a slightly generalized form of the question, from which by

- *Theorem1 (Szalay) "if the positive integers n,m, and x with $n \gt m$ satisfy $$2^{n-m} + 1 = {x^2-1\over 2^m} $$
  then (...uninteresting cases omitted...)  (iii) $(n,m,x) \in \{(5,4,7),(9,4,23) \}$."*
  The case $x=23$ is exactly that cases where $x$ is ***not*** of the form $2^k - 1$ and yet $f_e(x)$ ***is*** of that form and thus $x$ can iterate towards zero.
- *Theorem2 (Szalay) "if the positive integers n,m, and x with $n \gt m$ satisfy $$2^{n-m} - 1 = {x^2-1\over 2^m} $$
  then (...uninteresting cases omitted...)  (iii) $(n,m,x) \in \{(5,3,5),(7,3,11),(15,3,181) \}$."*
  The cases $x=11$ and $x=181$ are exactly that cases where $x$ is ***not*** of the form $2^k + 1$ and yet $f_e(x)$ ***is*** of that form and thus both $x$ can iterate towards zero.

***Thus: we have the proof, that***

- the three cases found in (eq 6) $$ (t,e,n_1,n_2) \in  \{ (1,2,23,33), (-23,1,-181,4095), (1,1,11,15) \} $$ are the only solutions not in the rows $4$ and $5$ ($t=-1$ or $t=0$) in the above table, which iterate towards zero.
- Since ***all*** other cases not in the rows $4$ and $5$ ($t=-1$ or $t=0$) increase by one iteration, all that other cases must diverge to infinity.

Szalay, László: The equations $2^N \pm 2^M \pm 2^L = z^2 $, Indag. Mathem. N.S., 131-142, 2002. See the downloadable links at the comments/answer of [my earlier question in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375245/7710)

---

*Update3:* Curious fact on the iteration of $a_1=13$. The fractional part of the double-log to base *2* seems to converge to some limit. See the protocol of the first *30* iterations (odd steps only):

```
 k   log_2(log_2(a_k))
-----------------------
[1, 1.88769671439]
[2, 2.13498231840]
[3, 2.53140883896]
[4, 2.91881409881]
[5, 3.59984673966]
[6, 4.26670326276]
[7, 5.02226916018]
[8, 5.95409288384]
[9, 6.88253436364]
[10, 7.85787043544]
[11, 8.84851166124]
[12, 9.84223857933]
[13, 10.8390917800]
[14, 11.8379099584]
[15, 12.8371215392]
[16, 13.8367271679]
[17, 14.8365299418]
[18, 15.8364559751]
[19, 16.8364066619]
[20, 17.8363820046]
[21, 18.8363727580]
[22, 19.8363681347]
[23, 20.8363658230]
[24, 21.8363635114]
[25, 22.8363627408]
[26, 23.8363623555]
[27, 24.8363622111]
[28, 25.8363621147]
[29, 26.8363620786]
[30, 27.8363620606]
```

Couldn't proceed further due to digit-length of occuring integers $a_k$ with finite memory...
Defining
$$b=2^{2^{0.836362060564583494096400006341-3}} \approx 
 1.1673140482117283628568828285728 ...$$
then it seems, we get approximation $a_k \to b^{2^k}$ depending on increasing precision of $b$ in the

Comment: Hi, Gottfried. Very nice!  I hadn't noticed this, the detail being that @username inside an answer does not generally produce a notification for that user. Maybe same for questions...  So, you appear to have proved the whole thing, including a classification.

Comment: @Will - yes, happy that 3 or 4 days of grilling myself led to a result at all. I like it especially because it is the first case of something like collatz-iteration-style where a proof of divergence of some orbits is known to me - the "divergent"-cases seem to have little attention in general...

Answer (score 3):

About Eric Syder's comment:  suppose $   x^2 - 1 = 2^k y$  with $x,y$ odd.  We wish to investigate what happens when $y \leq x \; . \; \;$  Note that $\gcd(x+1, x-1)  = 2$  because $x \equiv 1,3 \pmod 4.$  One of the $x \pm  1 $ is $\equiv 2 \pmod 4. $

Let us make the name $  \delta = \pm 1.$    Then we may demand
$$ x + \delta \equiv 2 \pmod 4$$
This tells us that the integer $ \frac{x + \delta}{2} $  is odd. We also have
$$      \frac{x + \delta}{2}   \frac{x - \delta}{2} = 2^{k-2}y$$
By repeated division by $2$   it follows that
$$ \frac{x - \delta}{2^{k-1}} = w $$   is an odd positive integer,  with
$$\frac{x + \delta}{2} \; \frac{x - \delta}{2^{k-1}} = y $$
IF  WE ASSUME $$ w = \frac{x - \delta}{2^{k-1}}  \geq 3,  $$
we find
$$   y = w \frac{x + \delta}{2}  \geq 3 \frac{x + \delta}{2} \geq \frac{3x - 3}{2}$$
The assumption $ w \neq 1$  has led us to $y \geq \frac{3x - 3}{2}$  The hypothesis that $x \geq y$  now says  $x \geq \frac{3x - 3}{2},$   or
$ 2x \geq 3x - 3,$ or $3 \geq x$

If $ x \geq y$   and $  x \geq 5$  in $   x^2 - 1 = 2^k y,$   we find that $w=1$  in $ \frac{x - \delta}{2^{k-1}} = w .$   So that $ x - \delta = 2^{k-1} .$  or
$$   x = \pm 1 + 2^{k=1}$$

Comment: Let’s suppose everything you’ve said is correct. Why don’t you want to also investigate when $y>x?$ For example, starting with $11,$ we get: $11\to 15=2^k-1,$ and therefore spirals down to $0.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's useful to focus on $x \ge y$, because that defines the cases where, with certainty, we eventually hit zero. Knowing that, we know that any other number that goes to zero (like $11$) must go *through* one of the others described by Will here.